# Inserting Query Results into Singlestore Table with Python and Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-insert, singlestore

I have parameterized queries with f strings such that the queries will select some data from a series of tables and joins, and I want to insert the resulting set of data into another pre-created table (tables been designed to house these results).

Python executes the code but the query results never show up in my table.

Assuming `target_table` is already created in singlestore database:

```
qry_load = 'insert into target_table select * from some_tables'
conn = engine.connect()
trans = conn.begin()
try:
    conn.execute(qry_load)
    trans.commit()
except:
    trans.rollback()
    raise
```

The code executes and acts as if all is ok, but the data never shows up in the target table.

How do I see what singlestore is passing back to better debug what is happening within the database?

Comment: What does your connection string look like? It shouldn't matter, but I'm curious as to which driver you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `begin()` with `cursor()` function:

```
conn = engine.connect()
trans = conn.cursor()
```

If not resolved

1- Verify structure of source and destination tables if they are same or not.

2- remove `try ,except and rollback()` block so you can know the actual error.

Ex.

```
qry_load = 'insert into target_table select * from some_tables'
conn = engine.connect()
trans = conn.cursor()
conn.execute(qry_load)
trans.commit()
```